# Remote monitoring Linux server from Ubuntu workstation via SSH

Tags: ssh, monitoring, remote

I am looking for a convenient way to monitor my Ubuntu server from my laptop (running Ubuntu Desktop). I understand this is easily achievable by SSHing to the server and running commands, but I'd like to do it on the fly, without going through the process.

I'd like to see load graphs, processes, users, etc... just by opening a window.
A good example would be MySQL Workbench, it allows to connect via SSH to the server and watch what's happening with MySQL in realtime, graphs provide a nice 'feel' of the loads.

Is anyone familiar with a Linux software that does that? Or an alternative solution perhaps?

UPDATE: Just to clarify, the monitoring I am looking for is a really basic one, similar to what you would get in your task manager. Just a general graph of CPU, RAM and network and a list of processes. For convenience I am looking for something that is installed and connects to the server (SSH preferably), not a web interface. I'd like to be able to take a look at it on the fly during a lecture and such.

Comment: What is the process? An X client, such as a graphical program showing load graphics can display on your laptops X server. You "just" need to start it and tell it to connect to that X server, as well as tell the display to allow the attachment. (most of this is what you get for free by using X11 with X forwarding enabled)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can SSH to the server and run any console or GUI util.

To run GUI program, for example, `gnome-system-monitor` you need to `ssh` with `-X` option

```
-X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host
             basis in a configuration file.
```

for instance,

`ssh -X user@server`

and then,

`gnome-system-monitor`

it shows next info:

**Processes**

[image]

**Resources**
[image]

**File Systems**
[image]

You can install and run also lots of programs. For example

`Glances` and `Pysensors` are described well in this close thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu

also you may consider these applications to monitor bunches of things on your server, read more for each:

`wmctrl`

`iotop`

`bum`

`smartmontools`

`top`

`hardinfo`

Answer (score 2):

There's a boatload of monitoring software out there:

- [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)
- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
- [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org/)

to only name a few. Without knowing your special requirements it's difficult to give good recommendations.

Comment: Something of a standard, useful monitoring, CPU, RAM, disk, network, etc...